# Spring Boot - Hibernate Validation behaves different in Tomcat and Jetty

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, tomcat, jetty

I've develop many Spring Boot Apps (using old version *1.5.21.RELEASE*), and I've always used **Tomcat** as it's the default in Spring Boot.

Now I needed to change to **Jetty** which was no major task, just excluding Tomcat and adding Jetty dependency. So far so good!

When I run it for the firs time, with a clean DB, it was failing due to a `ConstraintViolation`, looking at it was a custom validation message I set up on the `User` entity. This is my entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Data
public class User{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your username")
    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;


    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "telephone")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide a telephone number")
    private String telephone;
}
```

In the **users** table the column `telephone` allows NULL values. The validations used in the entity were meant for the Web CRUD Controller, having a `@Valid` before the `@RequestBody` of the `@Controller` endpoint, alongside with a `BindingResult`, which works good for both Tomcat and Jetty.

Then when the app startups I create a defaultUser, setting default values for all of its attributes **except for the telephone** number, which is kept null.

What it's strange to me is that it does not fail with Tomcat, but it does with Jetty. I mean, I have this line:

```java
userRepository.save(defaultUser);
```

As said the defaultUser has a NULL telephone number. As the **@NotEmpty** annotation is part of the `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty`, I think that the correct behavior is to fail when storing data in the DB if the constraint is not met, just as the Jetty servlet does. But I can stop wondering why it does not fails with Tomcat.

#### UPDATE

Moreover, this **@NotEmpty** annotation was added long time ago. Now that I'm making my head around this again, its a NotEmpty, not a NotNull constraint, so it does not matter if my DB allows NULLS or not, I just didn't want this field to be left empty (empty String ""). So one more time, I'm guessing why Tomcat let me store a `User` with an empty telephone number? And this has more than 2 years old and been used in over 10 different projects (it's a User management plugin I use across multiple apps), and never ever fail until I switch to Jetty.

#### build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.21.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'java'
}


apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply from:   'buildscripts/jacoco.gradle'

group = 'ar.com.sebasira'
version = '0.1.2-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}


ext{
    lombokVersion = '1.16.20'
}



configurations {
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc')

    // Use JETTY instead of Tomcat
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")

    compile('org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.7.0')
    compile("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0")
    compile('org.cryptonode.jncryptor:jncryptor:1.2.0')
    compile("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5")


    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")
    annotationProcessor ("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")


    compile("com.github.darrachequesne:spring-data-jpa-datatables:4.3")

    
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.8.0")


    runtime ('net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.15')


    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.15')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')

    // InMemory DB
    testCompile "com.h2database:h2:1.4.199"

    // Mockito
    compile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4"
}
```

Comment: One common enough issue is that you have duplicate classes (on different versions) in your classpath.  That can easily explain the differences you are seeing.  Run a duplicate class check plugin on your build tool (if you haven't yet).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've just run a Find Duplicate Class plugin and it founds none! Any other thoughts?

Comment: can you show your pom.xml

Comment: I'll add my build.gradle